# Installing NetCDF

Tags: installation, libraries

I would like to write a fortran program which uses NetCDF. 
In order to do so, I have to have the netcdf-module somewhere on my harddisc, and tell my compiler where to find it.
In Synaptic, the following packages are installed:

```
netcdf-bin
nco
netcdf-doc
libnetcdf-dev
libnetcdf6
```

libnetcdf-dev, especially, promises "everything needed for developing in C, C++,
Fortran 77, and Fortran 90"; however, I cannot find the libraries anywhere on my system, and accordingly, I cannot develop anything.
Where might the libraries be? They are neither in /usr/share, nor in /usr/lib.
And how, in general, can I found out where a package installs its files on my machine?

Answer (score 4):

If you open Synaptic and focus on any installed package then click "Properties" button, you can see dialog with "Installed Files" tab.

So netcdf libraries are in `/usr/lib/` and include files in `/usr/include` if you installed libnetcdf-dev through packaging system

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using system tools, [nc-config](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2012/utilities/Nc-config.html) and nf-config can help you find those details. This may be helpful if netcdf was compiled by you or someone else in your organization.

I believe `nf-config` only started shipping sometime after netcdf 4.2 was released, because the fortran lib was split into a different package then. So, if you fail to find the relevant fortran information with `nc-config`, check if `nf-config` exists somewhere and use it instead.

From [netcdf 4.2 release notes](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/news/entry/netcdf_4_2_release):

> Beginning with version 4.2, the three [c, c++, fortran] libraries are being released as separate packages.

Finally, here's a [sample output](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2012/utilities/popup_utilities_Nc-config_1.html) of `nc-config --all`:

```
This netCDF 4.2.1.1 has been built with the following features: 

  --cc        -> gcc
  --cflags    ->  -I/usr/local/include -I/share/ed/local/spike/include
  --libs      -> -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdf

  --has-c++   -> no
  --cxx       -> 
  --has-c++4  -> yes
  --cxx4      -> g++

  --fc        -> gfortran
  --fflags    -> -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include
  --flibs     -> -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lnetcdf
  --has-f90   -> yes

  --has-dap   -> yes
  --has-nc2   -> yes
  --has-nc4   -> yes
  --has-hdf5  -> yes
  --has-hdf4  -> no
  --has-pnetcdf-> no
  --has-szlib -> 

  --prefix    -> /usr/local
  --includedir-> /usr/local/include
  --version   -> netCDF 4.2.1.1
```

The left column has the options that can be sent to `nc-config` instead of `--all` to produce more specific output.